# Type T electrical box fill capacity

Tags: wiring

I am using a 4cu in TYPE T body with 1/2" connections at three places. All wires are 14 AWG THHN. Some wires pass through the body unbroken, others are spliced into a single three wire overhead light fixture. How many wires can fit within this body?  I am also using WAGO connectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about it.  T-type or any other conduit body (straight, LB, LL, LR) **are not intended for splices**.  They are usually too small.

### Two completely different sets of rules.

**Junction box rules** allow splices and devices.  They follow a "cubic-inch rule" - for #14 wire each "wire" takes 2 cubic inches, you get 4 grounds for the price of 1,  1 "wire count" covers all cable clamps, and 2 "wire counts" cover any yoke (receptacle, switch).

**Conduit body rules** allow "pass-through" only - no splices at all. No devices.  Real simple: If the conduit body's cross-section is twice the cross-section of the conduit, then it's allowed any number of wires legal in the conduits.

Last time I said it this way, someone got annoyed. But the simple fact is that a junction box with no splices or devices is allowed to follow the *conduit body* rules.   And conversely, a conduit body *with splices or devices* MUST follow the junction-box rules.

For instance if you have four 1" conduits coming into a 4x4 (30 cubic inch) box.  1" conduit is allowed seven #6 wires.  So *fourteen #6 wires* could be crossing amongst these conduits in this tiny 4x4 box.  That's OK if there are no splices, because that places it under the *conduit body* rules.

### Yours qualifies as a junction box.

However, as in your case, you have splices -- so you are under the *junction box* rules.  You must count 2 cubic inches for every wire in every splice, plus, 2 cubic inches for all passthroughs.  **Your junction box** is *comically* too small at 4 c.i.  It's not made for that.

You need a box *made to be* a junction box.

You didn't say how many wires. But common 4x4x1.5" boxes are 21 cubic inches.  4x4 deep boxes are 30 ci, and 4-11/16 (120mm) boxes are 42 ci.  I prefer the latter, nobody ever complained about extra cubic inches.

### Cheat -- run out, and back!

If you don't want to replace the conduit body, there's one cheat you can do, if. you have the conduit fill to spare.  Don't make the splice at the conduit body.  Take both groups of wires all the way to the lamp box, and make the splice there.  It creates a redundant route (aka "circuity" sir-cue-y-tee), but it means all wires are passing through, which makes it a conduit body again!

Yes, that involves wasting some THHN wire if you've already wired it. But the wire is probably too short even if you pull it all out and replace the conduit body with a J-box (which I have had to do).  Every wire must come at least 6" into a junction box to be spliced there.

Answer (score 2):

### 4 cubic inches isn't enough space for much of anything, so you're better off using a box here instead

4 cubic inches is only enough room for a splice between 2 14AWG wires, so you'll need to use something like a FS box of the appropriate configuration here instead, along with a blank faceplate for said box.

Answer (score 2):

A #14 wire takes 2.0 cubic inches of box fill just to pass through unbroken. Two of them take up your entire box, as would one pair spliced together. You need a significantly larger box for several wires and splices.

Comment: Great. going up to a 31cu.in